# Checking Someone is a Member Of One of Many Groups Using Partial Group Name

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, directoryservices, account-management

I'm a bit stuck trying to work something into my code.

What I'm looking to do is to work out whether someone is a member of any one of a collection of groups. I'm not worried about which group specifically, I only want to know:

"Is user "X" a member of at least one of this collection of groups?"

The good news is, ALL these group names start in the same way:

- Google-FullAccess
- Google-RestrictedAccess
- Google-MailOnly
- Google-Enterprise etc.

Here's what I'm using to check for a specific group:

```
Dim ctx As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext = New DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext(DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ContextType.Domain, "net.mydomain.co.uk")
Dim user As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal = DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, tbxuserID.Text)
Dim googleFull As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal = DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "Google-FullAccess")
If user.IsMemberOf(googleFull) Then
    GoogleAccess = 1
    GoTo Proceed
End If
```

I then repeat this block of code to check for the next group and so on.

Is there a way I can adapt this to check for any group *starting with* "Google-"? Here's what I'd like to do but obviously doesn't work:

```
Dim googleCheck As DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal = DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "Google-*")
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! The following works for me (after working out and storing the DistinguishedName in a String variable from a previous query - I also declare GoogleCheck as a Boolean variable beforehand):

```
Dim rootEntry As DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry = New DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=net,DC=mydomain,DC=co,DC=uk")
Dim srch As DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher = New DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(rootEntry)
srch.SearchScope = DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree
srch.Filter = "(&(CN=Google-*)(objectCategory=group)(member=" + DistinguishedName + "))"
Dim res = srch.FindOne()
If res IsNot Nothing Then
    GoogleCheck = True
Else
    GoogleCheck = False
End If
```